# SQL NOW() gives 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, types

i have done SQL insertion with  NOW() using codeigniter.
instead of current time i got  0000-00-00 00:00:00 in my db recode.
i am using latest WAMP as my server and cannot understand the where is the problem.
please help me.

```
function createform($form_data)
{
    $this->db->set('created', 'NOW()',TRUE);
    $this->db->insert('amfbases', $form_data);

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() == '1')
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Damn you must be in a time pocket. Can you go and check if Jesus really existed?

Comment: MySQL supports zero dates, for when a value is specified that isn't a valid date.  It's on by default, and can be turned off if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check your column data type, and did u quote the NOW(), like `insert into table values ("NOW()");` ?

**updated**

```
$this->db->set('created', time(),TRUE);
```

or

```
$this->db->set('created', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),TRUE);
```

or update your table schema to
`add_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

**updated 2**

`NOW()` is specify to MYSQL, PHP interpreted it as string, and cannot mix both together

Comment: `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,

Comment: @Kombuwa: if this case, `$this->db->set('created', time(),TRUE);` or `$this->db->set('created', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),TRUE);` should be able to fix your problem

Comment: @Kombuwa : `$this->db->set('created', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),TRUE);` cause did not notice is a datetime data type

Comment: thanks `$this->db->set('created', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),TRUE);` is perfectly working.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the right way to do this (i.e. pass sql functions to db) is to specify third param to be `FALSE`
Example:

```
$this->db->set('created', 'NOW()', FALSE); // notice FALSE
```

That will cause codeigniter to pass second param without quoting it resulting in sql interpreting it as function.

Useful for:

```
$this->db->set('counter', 'counter + 1', FALSE);
```

For reference look: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html